# ¿Por qué MySQL permite insertar texto en campo tipo entero(INT)?

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

¿Por qué MySQL permite insertar texto en campo tipo entero(INT)?

Por ejemplo, tengo esto:

```
INSERT INTO `estudiante` (`usuarioID`, `identidad`, `correo`, `institucion`)
               VALUES ("32", 'xxx', 'prueba@gmail.com', 'exterior')
```

el segundo campo es identidad que es entero por que  no me da error al insertar un texto

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?
se supone que es un int no debería permitir texto, lo convierte en cero

Aquí esta el diseño de la tabla:

```
    CREATE TABLE `estudiante` (
    `usuarioID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `identidad` INT(20) NOT NULL,
    `correo` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    `institucion` VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`usuarioID`)
)
```

Comment: Si nos compartes el script con la definición de la tabla talvés sea más sencillo encontrar una solución. Es posible que ese campo se haya diseñado de forma diferente a la que esperas al momento de usarlo.

Comment: "Se supone que es un int, no debería permitir cero". Claro que sí, un cero es un int xD

Comment: perdon quise decir texto @user2930137

Comment: ¿Cuál es el contenido que llevas en cada una de las variables que deseas insertar?

Comment: @SergioRomero, recuerda [edit] tu pregunta. Los comentarios son temporales.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

El comportamiento que observas está descrito en [la documentación aquí](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/constraint-invalid-data.html):

> By default, MySQL is forgiving of invalid or improper data values and coerces them to valid values for data entry. [...]
>
> If you are not using strict mode, then whenever you insert an “incorrect” value into a column, [...] MySQL sets the column to the “best possible value” instead of producing an error
>
> ***If you try to store a string that does not start with a number into a numeric column, MySQL Server stores 0.***

(Pobre) traducción:

> Por defecto, MySQL te perdona la entrada de datos inválidos o inapropiados y los convierte (tuerze) a la fuerza a valores válidos para poder insertarlos. [...]
>
> Si no estás usando el modo estricto, entonces cuando insertas un valor "incorrecto" en una columna, [...] MySQL asigna "el mejor valor posible" en vez de producir un error.
>
> ***Si tratas de asignar una cadena (texto) que no comienza con un número a una columna de tipo numérico, MySQL asigna un 0.***

Nota aparte, esta es una de las varias razones que no tengo mucho respeto por MySQL como base de datos. Si tomas la pena de leer la página entera, es increíble la forma como MySQL, por defecto, está dispuesto a torcer/convertir los datos con tal de evitar darte un error. Lo que ellos llaman hacerte un favor, yo llamo corrupción de los datos.

En todo caso, aplicando la regla documentada, esto significa que MySQL inserta y convierte las cadenas siguientes de esta manera:

```
'xxx' --> 0
'xxx12' --> 0
'12xxx' --> 12
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://rextester.com/JYRIIB54981)</kbd>

Si como yo, no te parece correcto este comportamiento, puedes modificar la forma como MySQL maneja estas situaciones.  Nuevamente, como dice [la documentación](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/constraint-invalid-data.html):

> You can enable strict SQL mode to select more traditional treatment of bad values such that the server rejects them and aborts the statement in which they occur.
>
> You can select stricter treatment of input values by using the `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` or `STRICT_ALL_TABLES` SQL modes

(Pobre) traducción:

> Puedes activar el modo estricto SQL para elegir un manejo mas tradicional de valores incorrectos de forma que el servidor los rechaza y cancela la sentencia donde ocurren.
>
> Puedes seleccionar un manejo mas estricto de valores de entrada usando los modos SQL `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` o `STRICT_ALL_TABLES`.

Y, en efecto, si te aseguras que el `sql_mode` de tu sesión incluye `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES`, verás que MySQL te va a lanzar un error.

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://rextester.com/KDQG47153)</kbd>

Para ver el valor que tienes para `sql_mode`:

```
select @@sql_mode;
```

Ejemplo de cómo modificar el `sql_mode` de tu sesión:

```
SET sql_mode = 'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES';
```

Para mayor información sobre los *SQL modes* puedes seguir el enlace siguiente: [Server SQL Modes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html).

Answer (score 4):

En esos casos MySQL hace una conversión:

> You can specify an expression expr to provide a column value. This
>   might involve type conversion if the type of the expression does not
>   match the type of the column, and conversion of a given value can
>   result in different inserted values depending on the data type. For
>   example, inserting the string '1999.0e-2' into an INT, FLOAT,
>   DECIMAL(10,6), or YEAR column results in the values 1999, 19.9921,
>   19.992100, and 1999 being inserted, respectively. The reason the value stored in the INT and YEAR columns is 1999 is that the
>   string-to-integer conversion looks only at as much of the initial part
>   of the string as may be considered a valid integer or year. For the
>   floating-point and fixed-point columns, the string-to-floating-point
>   conversion considers the entire string a valid floating-point value.

O sea:

> Puede especificar una expresión `expr` para proporcionar un valor de
>   columna. Esto puede implicar **la conversión de tipo si el tipo de la
>   expresión no coincide con el tipo de la columna** y la conversión de
>   un valor dado puede dar lugar a diferentes valores insertados
>   dependiendo del tipo de datos. **Por ejemplo, al insertar la cadena
>   '1999.0e-2' en una columna INT**, FLOAT, DECIMAL (10,6) o YEAR, se
>   introducen los valores **1999**, 19.9921, 19.992100 y 1999
>   respectivamente. La razón por la cual el valor almacenado en las
>   columnas INT y YEAR es 1999 es que **la conversión de cadena a entero
>   parece sólo en la parte inicial de la cadena que puede considerarse un
>   entero o año válido**. Para las columnas de punto flotante y punto
>   fijo, la conversión de cadena a punto flotante considera la cadena
>   completa un valor de punto flotante válido.

Fuente: [Manual de Referencia de MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html)

Comment: Muchas gracias x la ayuda