# ¿Como se tratan los datos de tipos String cuando contienen numeros en una base de datos?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Tengo 3 campos de tipo `int` declarados en MYSQL. En la primera consulta se puede apreciar que ingrese en values datos de tipo int, que serán aceptados por la base de datos ya que son de tipo `int`.

```
INSERT INTO FACTORAMBIENTAL(temperatura,humedadsuelo,humedadrelativa)
VALUES (1,2,3)
```

Pero si genero un segunda consulta en la cual los datos de `values` los declaro de tipo `varchar` igual se ingresan a la base de datos como de tipo `int` aunque estén las comillas que lo declaren de tipo `varchar`.

```
INSERT INTO FACTORAMBIENTAL(temperatura,humedadsuelo,humedadrelativa)
VALUES ('1','2','3')
```

¿Por qué sucede esto si se supone que, si tengo una campo declarado de tipo `int`, no debiera aceptar un `varchar`, que es lo que pasa? ¿Y por qué se almacena como si fueran de tipo `int`?

Answer (score 0):

MySql permite por defecto que ingresen datos invalidos y trata de forzarlo a un valor que sea valido para insertar.
Esto se puede desactivar cambiando una variable.

Acá te dejo una respuesta donde lo explican mejor: [link](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/55685/99341)

Comment: Gracias por el apoyo, pero cuando la respuesta esta duplicada en la misma comunidad, en lugar de responder enlazandola, lo conveniente aquí es reportarla para cerrarla por duplicado. Saludos